# Debug React. Identify Which prop was changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, react-devtools

For debugging my react app I want to know which prop was changed. When the application runs it executes `componentWillReceiveProps` infinite times. I don't know which prop was received. Is there any way to identify the modified props by comparing `this.props` and `nextProps` or by any other way

Comment: May be stringify both `this.props` and `newProps` and console.log to cross check in `componentWillReceiveProps`

Comment: @Cyril Can't stringify `this.props' . `Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON' error occured.

Comment: Then may be you might use this `https://www.npmjs.com/package/deep-object-diff` and console.log the report. but you need to remove it post debugging as this is an overhead.

Comment: could you show your code please, especially `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this package: [maicki/why-did-you-update](https://github.com/maicki/why-did-you-update) (about 3k stars on Github as of writing).

> Why-did-you-update is a function that monkey patches React and notifies you in the console when potentially unnecessary re-renders occur.

Answer (score 0):

I actually created a tool yesterday that helps with this problem https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-use-compare-debugger.

The idea is that by including a simple `useCompareDebugger("myComponent", props)` it will automatically log changes to props each render. Within here, the key bit is it details whether values are referentially equal, which is how React does shallow comparisons to determine when it should re-render.

[image]